# How to handle trunked response with Http client apis

Tags: scala, spray, chunked

Is there any code samples to show how to handle trunked response messages? (http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-can/http-client/#chunked-responses)

For example, I may use spray-can's http-client to access a service will response a big file in trucked way.
And I'd like to handle the trucked messages accordingly to save the big file in my local disk.

Thanks

Leon